# Determine if parameter is regular expression?

Tags: powershell

I have created a Powershell routine for setting mp3 tags on songs, where I'd like some of my parameters to act as either a regular expession or a "simple" string. To be specific, if the parameter can be said to work as a regular expression, the function should try to use this for retrieving its value; if it can't, it should simply use that value.

I've just browsed Parameter sets, and don't think this would suit me since I want to be flexible with the parameter handling; i.e. I'd like several parameters to act this way independently. But maybe I'm wrong in this? Anyway, help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is very unintuitive/unexpected for a parameter to sometimes act like a regex and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the try/catch if you use:

```
 IF ($string -as [regex])
```

If the cast is successful it will return the regex, if not it will return $null, so used as a boolean test in the IF, it will be $true if it is a valid regex, and $false if it is not.

That being said, the I'd agree with Joey that you should settle on a single match type (either wildcard or regex) and stick with that.  There's too much potential for unintended consequences in trying to determine if a regex metacharacter was intended to be match literally or not.

Comment: Thanks, this was the cleanest answer

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that nobody can remember everything, all the time :).  Maybe that's another argument for "pair programming".

Answer (score 1):

You can try converting the string to a regular expression and look for failures. If there is an exception, just use it as string:

```
$isParamRegex = $(try { $null = [regex]$Param; $true } catch { $false })
```

As for the parameter type, just make it a `string` and document it appropriately.

However, I'd say you might want to go a different route there:

- Either make the argument always a regex, to avoid surprises with metacharacters.
- Or make it a pattern for `-like` instead of `-match` which is a bit more predictable for users (imho).
- In both cases provide a `LiteralParam` argument, akin to `LiteralPath` to just pass things as plain strings which are handled as such.

Comment: Thanks for the input, and for the warning. The "users" will for the foreseable future be only me, so I hope "they" can cope with the possible confusion ;). But you're absolutely right if this were to be a more common script; I've had that situation myself at work, trying to explain 'smart' parameters like this (_"If it's a number, it will do this, but if it contains the characters a-e it will do that. But only if..."_)